# How to store user answers in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We are trying to store user answers on questions. Answer is id based. When user comes to site we need to get all question ids to know that he had answered. Question count can be about 50000 or more. Currently, we are storing data in sql server using appendable blob (varbinary(max)). But we are searching database that can handle that situation. Casandra can give us non blob scheme and master - master replication. What is right way to store it in casandra? I known lists are not recommended for such situation. Does separate table give us suitable performance (<20-30ms) with composite key?

Comment: Do you need just to store IDs? How would they used after retrieval - do you show a list of answers to user?

Comment: Yes, I can store ids, but I prefer to store as (answeredon,questionid,answerid). They will be used to exclude answered questions and to show history. I can separate history and exclusions. I think set is suitable for it. But not sure.

Comment: for collections, it's not recommended to go with more than couple of hundreds of elements in collection...

Comment: I saw that recommendation, I assume that I need to find another database for it.

Comment: No, you can simply use design as outlined in my answer

Comment: do not use material-view and secondary indexes. instead, using separate tables are much performant one. they are cheap and scales easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand how you'll fetch the data, but usually, if you have only one collection-like column in your table, then you can always implement it as an additional column as clustering column - this will solve a problem with accessing the part of the answers, etc. - when you have answer ID as clustering column, you can fetch only range of the answers, but when you use `set`, then you need to fetch everything...

For example, if you have table like this:

```
create table answers (
  user_id text primary key,
  answers set<int>
)
```

it could be always converted from collection to following:

```
create table answers (
  user_id text,
  answer_id int,
  primary key (user_id, answer_id));
```

but actual table structure will depend on how you're performing queries for this data - this is primary requirement for data modeling for Cassandra.

P.S. I recommend to take DS220 course on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/), to learn more about data modellng, or grab [3rd edition of Cassandra book](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide), that was released recently - it has good chapter on data modeling.

Comment: We need to get all ids at real time. So, I need to store them in any other database. Casandra is not for it.  Am, I right? Thank for courses links.

Comment: why? you can always get all IDs by only specifying partition key in the `WHERE` condition... In Cassandra, you can specify partial primary key, the only hard requirement is partition key

Comment: Thank you need to test. We have some millions of users everyday and i have uncertainty about performance of that solution.

Comment: even 10M users a day, it's ~500-1000/sec at peak time - usually it's not a problem for Cassandra, if you design your schema correctly....